# how to orient of Z-local-axis through a given Point

Tags: transforms

I have a object 'A' with it's local-axis. And I have a Point 'B' with it's location (x,y,z)

Now I want to the Z-local axis (or X or Y-local axis) of 'A' toward to 'B' (the virtual straight line that Z-local axis be in goes through 'B'). of course the object 'A' not moving, only rotate.

is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just assign a [Damped Track](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/constraints/tracking/damped_track.html) constraint to object 'A'. (You can set any axis to track the target)..

[image]

If at some stage you want to remove the constraint but leave 'A' in place, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > 'Apply Visual Transforms'

Comment: thank you so much, I am new in Blender, I will try to do your way now

Comment: yes it work perfectly, thank you for helping

Comment: This is great, I completely missed this feature in the Blender manual. Thank you.